# Problems with a real path of the user in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, the test involves a sequence that includes logging in, clicking on various subpages, and then logging out. The test is configured for a total of 50 users. While JMeter reports that each user successfully completes the entire path, monitoring reveals that each user is only logging in, visiting the first subpage, and then logging out. Could you please help identify the issue causing users not to proceed to the next subpages?

I tried to record the test in JMeter, BlazeMeter. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, **it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter doesn't actually perform "clicks", it sends [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), waits for response and measures time in-between.

If the "click" doesn't cause a HTTP Request - it won't be recorded as it doesn't trigger any network activity.

In case you're absolutely sure that each "click" results in a HTTP Request I can think of the following possible reasons:

1. You either missed or incorrectly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters
2. JMeter is not [properly configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
3. You're trying to test something like single page application and subsequent calls are just being returned from [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)

So the first recommendation is cross-checking requests which are being sent from JMeter and from the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Given you will send the same requests as the real browser does you will get the same responses. You can also consider adding [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that i.e. response contains what it's supposed to contain as another level of confidence as JMeter automatically treats HTTP responses with [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful.